# A vertical line on the right hand side of the window after changing desktops

Tags: macos, desktop

When I navigate from left desktop window to right desktop window, a vertical line start appearing on the right hand side of the desktop. It only happens when navigating from left to right and if there is something small open rather than a maximised page/app/folder/file etc. See example below please. Restarting and [this blog post](https://www.adeepbite.com/vertical-line-on-macbook-air-screen/) didn't help. Any ideas?

Using MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

[image]

Comment: can you choose different background to see it better

Comment: It is still there with different backgrounds (inc solid colours).